# TimeoutError while inserting jsons to Postgres database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, bulkinsert

I want to insert my files to my database which are includes object arrays (rows). I have nearly eight thousand files in 25 folder and nearly 40000 records.

I am getting an **TimeoutError: ResourceRequest timed out.**

I try increase connection time of sequelize but its gives an error after first thousand rows. How can i insert 40000 rows data to my local database correct and efficiently?

```
let folders_path = path.join(__dirname, "extracted_subjects/*");

function bulk_insert() {
  glob(folders_path, readFolders);
}

function readFolders(err, folders) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("ERROR readFolders: ", err);
    return;
  }
  folders.forEach(function(file) {
    glob(path.join(file, "/*.json"), readFiles);
  });
}
function readFiles(err, files) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("ERROR readFiles: ", err);
    return;
  }
  files.forEach(async function(fileName) {
    //console.log(fileName);
    let promise = getData(fileName, "utf8")
      .then(data => {
        try {
          // Parse And Bulk Create
          let obj = JSON.parse(data);
          models.dream
            .bulkCreate(obj)
            .then(function() {
              console.log("File: inserted!");
            })
            .catch(err => console.log("Error", err));
        } catch (SyntaxError) {
          console.log("File: ", fileName);
          return;
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

    await promise;
  });
}

function getData(fileName, type) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile(fileName, type, (err, data) => {
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(data);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could increase default settings on your connection, like for example (you can read about those on documentation):

```
    dialectOptions:   {
      timeout: 30
    },
    operatorsAliases: Sequelize.Op,
    pool:             {
      max:            5,
      min:            0,
      idle:           30000,
      maxConnections: 5,
      maxIdleTime:    30
    },
```

but I suspect you biggest issue is that you are trying to read all the files and keep opening new connections to database and you don't have time to write them all in and they naturally go to timeout

I suspect this behaviour is not what you wanted to write

```
files.forEach(async function (fileName) {
  let promise = getData(fileName, 'utf8');
    // ...
  await promise;
});
```

This part of code is using words async and await, this is not making them sequential reads, they are still able to run in parallel. You are going to call `getData` function as fast as you can, and then start bombarding the `models.dream.bulkCreate`. The usage of `bulkCreate` makes no sense here either since you are not creating anything in bulk, rather one by one

options I could see for this are:

a) keep similar code, but go over files 25 by 25 parallel with one write per block, this change is a bit bigger, read 25 in memory, write them bulk in database, read next 25, etc...
b) keep similar code, but go over files 25 by 25 parallel with 25 writes per block, this change is a bit bigger, open and read 25 files and then for each one write just one row, then move on
c) keep similar code, but instead of reading each file and writing it into database, hold them in memory and write all the data just once at the end once you have all the data. however, in your case with this big data, you might run out of memory
d) if performance is not an issue, as in you want / need to do this once (in a while) you can simply loop over all the files and read them in sync mode, so it will always go one by one.

```
files.forEach(async function (fileName) {
  let data = fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf8'); // read the file sync

  try {
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(data); // try parsing
    models.dream                       // and inserting 
      .create(parsedData)              // this should not be bulkCreate, right??
       // this is kinda wrong, it doesn't automatically mean it 
       // is inserted, but it is copy paste from above
      .then(res => console.log('File: inserted!')) 
      .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
  } catch (SyntaxError) {console.log('File: ', fileName);}
};
```

What this piece of code is doing is making sure you actually go file by file in sequence, it will slow down execution considerably for your side, but since you originally stated you wanted to do this on your localhost I assume you have time to leave it running. You are still risking that you can read the files faster than database can handle writing it, but this time should not be to much different from sync read of next file and your system should be able to keep up, especially if you increase number of allowed connection in your pool.

For production wise, I would probably go with options a or b, depending if I knew ahead of time maximum sizes / number of the files.

Comment: I try your suggestion but my problem doesn't solved i think i missed something this was just for my hobby project. I try to write same code in python it works. Thank you.